# Логика конструктора при наследовании

Tags: c++, наследование, конструктор

Почему логика языка С++ позволяет производному классу пользоваться конструктором БЕЗ параметров базового класса, НО НЕ позволяет пользоваться конструктором с параметрами базового класса? Нужно создавать отдельный конструктор с параметрами для производного.

```
class Base    // базовый класс
{
public:
    Base() { }
    Base(int input) {}
};

class Derived : public Base  // производный класс
{
public:
    Derived() : Base () { }  // конструктор производного класса вызывает конструктор базового

    Derived(int inputD) : Base(inputD) { } // inputD передается в конструктор с параметром класса Base
};

int main()
{
    Base base(3);     // объект базового класса
    Derived der(4);   // объект производного класса
}
```

При создании конструктора производного класса использовали другой параметр. ЗАЧЕМ?

Comment: Поясните кодом, что Вы имеете в виду.

Comment: @ixSci Как я понимаю, интересует при наличии `Base::Base(int)` и при *отсутствии* `Derived::Derived(int)` вызова типа `Derived d(5);`...

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Можешь обьяснить? "Важной особенностью производного класса, является то, что хоть он и может использовать все методы и элементы полей protected и public базового класса, но он не может обратиться к конструктору с параметрами. Если конструкторы в производном классе не определены, при создании объекта сработает конструктор без аргументов базового класса. А если нам надо сразу при создании объекта производного класса внести данные, то для него необходимо определить свои конструкторы."

Comment: @Harry Почему? "Важной особенностью производного класса, является то, что хоть он и может использовать все методы и элементы полей protected и public базового класса, но он не может обратиться к конструктору с параметрами. Если конструкторы в производном классе не определены, при создании объекта сработает конструктор без аргументов базового класса. А если нам надо сразу при создании объекта производного класса внести данные, то для него необходимо определить свои конструкторы."

Comment: Уберите, пожалуйста, в коде всё лишнее. Почитайте, что есть [mcve].

Comment: Погодите... Как вы себе представляете - итак, конструкторы в производном классе не определены. Т.е. есть сгенерированный конструктор по умолчанию. Как вы себе представляете при этом вызов базового конструктора с параметрами? Какими параметрами? Как вы собираетесь их указывать? Набросайте свой *гипотетический* код, как бы вы хотели это видеть.

Comment: "Почему логика языка С++ позволяет производному классу пользоваться конструктором БЕЗ параметров базового класса, НО НЕ позволяет пользоваться конструктором с параметрами базового класса?" - здесь написана какая-то ерунда. Все конструкторы базового класса совершенно равноправны и ведут себя в производном классе одинаково, независимо от того, сколько у них параметров. Поэтому о чем идет речь в вашем вопросе - не ясно.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если базовый класс имеет конструктор без параметров, то он будет вызван неявно из конструктора производного класса. Т.е. писать что-то вроде `Derived() : Base() { }` не требуется.

Если же из конструктора производного класса (не важно, с параметрами или без) нужно вызывать конструктор базового класса, принимающий параметры, то требуется явно указать какие это будут параметры, т.е. прокидывания аргумента из конструктора производного класса в конструктор базового класса в виде один-к-одному по умолчанию нет, нужно написать это руками.

```
Derived(int i) : Base(i) { }
```

Всё это сделано для того, чтобы было ясно видно как трансформируется параметр. Ведь вполне может потребоваться и такая запись:

```
Derived(int i) : Base(f(i)) { }
```

где `f()` - некоторая функция преобразования, которая в общем случае может порождать тип, отличный от `int`, т.к. конструктор `Base` вполне может иметь версию с параметром другого типа. Пример:

```
Base(const char* c) {}
Derived(int i) : Base(itoa(i))
```

Также в с++11 появилась возможность наследования конструкторов для достижения эффекта сквозной передачи параметров. Таким образом вместо:

```
Derived(int i) : Base(i) { }
```

можно написать следующее:

```
using Base::Base;
```

Этой записью осуществляется прокидывание имеющихся сигнатур конструкторов базового класса в производный.